# need regular expression to extract for all files in zip file

Tags: c++, wildcard

Right now I am using `"*.*"` to extract files with all file types. It works fine it file name has dot in it. Sometimes I will have some binary files in the zip folder with no file extension to it.

What is the regular expression to use in such cases instead of "*.*"?

Comment: First shot is always checking the boost library functions.

Comment: This `*.*` is not a regex, thus, I changed the tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"*.*"` is a wildcard meaning any number of characters, followed by a dot, followed by an extension containing any number of characters. You can probably use the wildcard `"*"` to match any file.

Comment: Thanks rubystallion. That helped